# Use an isolation transformer for outdoor power tools in wet weather?

Tags: electrical, powertools

Wet snow is forecast and I have a new, small electric snow blower. Would it be safer to run the snow blower using an isolation transformer as compared to just plugging the blower into a GFI outlet?  (I am in New York and happen to own a Tripp Lite isolation transformer.)

Comment: You asked which is safer.  That is an opinion question. VTC.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Safer is an opinion question only if there are no large differences.  Which is safer to drink, lye or water?

Comment: That's a terrible analogy.  All your interactions with this question have been whiny and demanding, and it's clear you won't accept "there are no large differences".  Bottom line, you intended all along to write an off-topic question and you're being rude to people who gave you benefit of the doubt and wrote on-topic answers!

Comment: It is not an opinion but a fact that a GFCI is much safer but I understand internet only electricians would not understand this is why isolation transformers have to be monitored.

Comment: @EdBeal I am not contesting your statement about GFI being safer. I seek the reason.

Comment: Yehuda I stated in my answer that the GFCI will limit the current to 5ma. An isolation transformer has no limit other than the breaker 15 amps or more.  There are multiple code sections that require the primary and secondary grounding unless monitored.  So a GFCI will protect from lethal shock where there is a ground path a isolation transformer won’t

Answer (score 6):

Isolation transformers are useful for a variety of things. They can block the transfer of high-frequency noise from mains supply wiring into sensitive electronics -- this may be why Tripp Lite, a manufacturer of power-related items for IT equipment, made the one you have now. An isolation transformer can also protect users who, through some fault in equipment, may come into contact with live parts of the isolated system -- *so long as there isn't a second fault already present*.

Ground-fault protection looks at the current flowing out on the hot wire and the current returning on the neutral wire. If there's a discrepancy then current is flowing where it ought not to. We usually presume the current is flowing to "ground" and thus the failure is called "ground fault." We further presume that the current may be flowing through a person, so the trigger threshold is often set at a relatively safe-for-humans 5 mA.

For the case of outdoor power equipment it can be easily argued that GFCI offers better protection or safety than isolation does. Consider that isolation protection is effective only when there are no other faults. Will procedures be in place to routinely test and confirm absence of other faults? If a transient fault to a person occurs, how will that fault be detected? Maintenance won't repair a problem that it doesn't know exists. Isolation does not automatically de-energize the system when a fault occurs, so a second fault is still going to be damaging or fatal.

On the other hand, ground fault protection easily detects even the smallest fault from line to ground. It automatically de-energizes the system before personal injury occurs, and probably even before the person can sense the current flowing through them. Depending on the level of conductivity ground fault protection can possibly even detect a neutral-to-ground fault.

One might be tempted to use both GFCI and isolation. Don't do that. An isolated system operating downstream from a GFCI defeats the GFCI protection - the GFCI can't detect faults that occur on the load side of the isolation transformer.

Comment: Yep on everything you said. I kinda said the same thing in a comment. Great great answer, very thorough.   Great point in your last paragraph. You said it better than I did.  +

Comment: Greg the GFCI will not use the ground at all and would be absolutely fine after a isolation transformer. In fact this is why on a 2 wire receptacle code requires a ground to be added or a GFCI device to install a 3 wire receptacle. The way the GFCI works doesn't change the total on the 2 wires must be balanced or within 5ma or it trips and stops the flow.

Comment: @EdBeal agreed: GFCI *after* an isolation transformer will work correctly. But if they're arranged the other way around, ie a GFCI circuit feeds an isolation xfmr which then feeds the snowblower, the GFCI won't be able to detect faults on the secondary side of the transformer. The GFCI would see only that the hot and neutral currents to the transformer primary are balanced.

Comment: I do agree with that on the primary side a GFCI would not detect the fault, after re reading that is what you said.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO isolation will not protect from shock.
Code requires isolation systems to be monitored and or supervision this is not a residential thing.

The ground itself is what is being isolated and this prevents voltage on the ground from back feeding on the neutral. Or electrical noise from the supply is dampened.

You would still be required to have a GFCI for outside receptacles even if isolated and the gfci’s do not use ground they detect the supply and return balance (hot & neutral) more than 5 ma Tripp’s the circuit.

As I said you can still get a Lethal shock from an isolated source. A GFCI will trip prior to reaching a hazard level.

Lighting is an extreme form of isolated power and it finds its way to earth just as isolated voltages will.

Answer (score 1):

You should be perfectly safe powered by a GFCI outlet, that's exactly what they are designed to do.   Also, you'd have to tell us what isolation transformer you are talking about.  Some of them are very low power and may not be able to power a snow blower.  Where are you?  Isolation transformers aren't very common in the US.  In Canada you often see them in bathrooms.

Answer (score 0):

GFCI and try to avoid running over the cord is quite adequate.

Comment: For example, which is safer if I do happen to run over the cord?

Comment: If you run over the cord and cut it, you'll almost certainly have a leak to ground which would instantly trip the GFCI breaker or outlet. I believe a GFCI is safer than an isolation transformer.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Why do you think the GFI is safer than the isolation transformer?

Comment: Because an isolation transformer would continue to operate even if the power cord from it got cut. A GFCI breaker /outlet is DESIGNED to provide EXACTLY the type of protection you are looking for:  It cuts the current instantly if the power provided isn't exactly the same as what is being returned in the circuit because that power might be going thru a person.